# If I buy a physical copy of DMC: Devil May Cry, will it pick up a save file from the downloaded copy?

Tags: psn, dmc-devil-may-cry

I have recently downloaded DmC: Devil May Cry and I kind of like the game and would want it after my subscription ends so I was thinking of buying the physical game on disc from store and deleting the downloaded version.

Does anyone know if the physical game (disc) will recognize the save file or if I have to start everything from scratch?

Cannot find that this question has previously been asked (only the other way around (from disc to PSN downloaded game).

Hope someone can help me with this question.

Comment: It didn't for me with Lego Batman 2 the other way around. The saves from the physical disc were not recognized by the digital copy I bought in the sony store.

Comment: @jmfsg I've noticed for some reason some games have "digital version" or similar appended to the end of their name and maybe that's why saves don't work? Not sure though, don't think I've ever tried this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no general answer to this, since [some games are compatible and some are not](http://neogaf.com/forum/showthread.php?t=515243). You certainly could wait here until someone with exact same situation, but good option is to go to [official forum](http://www.capcom-unity.com/go/network/forum) and ask there.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, No; every game disc is manufactured with an ID, even downloadable games have unique IDs. This is used to prevent game save sharing and cheating. However, this is only to my knowledge.

Comment: This sounds completely made-up.

Comment: Some game have this sort of protection, others don't. You also need a credible source to proof it does... Plus nowadays games don't have that sort of protection whatsoever; it's instead binded to the accounts logged into that game (ie. GTA V)